# Getting Variable from Applescript and using in Python

Tags: python, applescript

Is there any easy way to use an applescript like:

```
set theText to text returned of (display dialog "Please insert Text here:" default answer "" with title "exchange to python" with icon 1)
```

And use the "theText" variable in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also run a python script with command line input from AppleScript:

```
--make sure to escape properly if needed
set pythonvar to "whatever"
set outputvar to (do shell script "python '/path/to/script' '" & pythonvar & "'")
```

Ned's example has python calling AppleScript, then returning control to python, this is the other way around. Then in Python access list of parameters:

```
import sys
var_from_as = sys.argv[1] # for 1rst parameter cause argv[0] is file name
print 'this gets returned to AppleScript' # this gets set to outputvar
```

Comment: Sure, it all depends on how your application here is organized: is the AppleScript the "main" program or is the Python code.  Either is valid; in general, though, I think one would be better off writing as much as possible in Python and using as little AppleScript as necessary - but I admit to being a bit prejudiced.  Using AppleScript to provide native GUI input and output for other languages like Python is a simple but effective technique.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it.  Probably the simplest way, since it does not rely on any third-party Python modules, is to run the script in a child process using the OS X [`osascript` command line utility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osascript.1.html).  By default, `osascript` returns any output from the AppleScript execution to stdout which can be then be read in Python.  You can try it out in the Python interactive interpreter.

With Python 3.4.1:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> theText = subprocess.check_output(['osascript', '-e', \
       r'''set theText to text returned of (display dialog "Please insert Text here:" default answer "" with title "exchange to python" with icon 1)'''])
>>> theText
b'Hell\xc3\xb6 W\xc3\xb2rld!\n'
>>> print(theText.decode('UTF-8'))
Hellö Wòrld!
```

With Python 2.7.7:

```
>>> theText
'Hell\xc3\xb6 W\xc3\xb2rld!\n'
>>> print(theText.decode('UTF-8'))
Hellö Wòrld!
```

For a real world application, you'll probably want to do some error checking and/or exception catching.