# Python get variables from AppleScript program

Tags: python, applescript

I have recently been working with AppleScript, and was wondering if there is a way to get variables from AppleScript, and use them in Python. For example, say I have an AppleScript program called `test.scpt` and it has the following code in it:

```
set var1 to "hello"
set var2 to "hi"
```

In my python, I want to do something (like print) the values of those two variables:

```
print(var1)
print(var2)
```

I looked at answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24445991/getting-variable-from-applescript-and-using-in-python), however most of the ones I found at years old. Is there a newer/better way to do this, and if not, what is the best way?

EDIT:
I have also tried using `osascript` and `os.system` together, however I cannot store the output as a variable, as to the best of my knowledge osascript just runs the code, but cannot store variables.

Comment: You can call handlers and get properties using some PyObjC - how are you implementing the script?

Comment: @red_menace the AppleScript?

Comment: Yes.  The second link in foo's answer is a quick and easy way to implement and instantiate the AppleScript for Python.  The variables would need to be properties though, since they have getters/setters.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options:

- [NSAppleScript](https://pypi.org/project/py-applescript/)
- [AppleScript-ObjC+PyObjC](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. I looked at both the links and could not find anything which was the answer to what I am looking for. Could you clarify, or did I miss something?

Comment: Both allow you to load AppleScripts and call their handlers and, unlike `osascript`, the script’s state persists between calls. As RM says, just add handlers to access your AppleScripts’ state. (While it is technically possible to introspect an AppleScript’s properties, the API for doing so is hideously arcane, archaic C.)

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Some magic can be used to access properties, for example `MyASClass._.testProperty`